# Django URL patterns have stopped matching

Tags: django

I have been cutting my teeth on python and django with a specialized membership application (My_Members).  The slightly edited footprint is:

```
|-- Billing
|   |-- __init__.py
|   |-- admin.py
|   |-- apps.py
|   |-- models
|   |   |-- __init__.py
|   |   |-- account.py
|   |   |-- fees.py
|   |   `-- payment.py
|   |-- tests.py
|   |-- urls.py
|   |-- views
|   |   |-- __init__.py
|   |   |-- account.py
|   |   `-- fees.py
|   `-- views.py
|-- My_Members
|   |-- __init__.py
|   |-- settings.py
|   |-- urls.py
|   `-- wsgi.py
|-- Manager
|   |-- __init__.py
|   |-- admin.py
|   |-- apps.py
|   |-- models
|   |   |-- __init__.py
|   |   `-- group.py
|   |-- tests.py
|   `-- views
|       |-- __init__.py
|       `-- group.py
|-- Members
|   |-- __init__.py
|   |-- account_adapter.py
|   |-- admin.py
|   |-- apps.py
|   |-- forms
|   |   |-- __init__.py
|   |   |-- profile.py
|   |   `-- student.py
|   |-- models
|   |   |-- __init__.py
|   |   |-- profile.py
|   |   |-- rank.py
|   |   |-- student.py
|   |   `-- title.py
|   |-- urls.py
|   `-- views
|       |-- __init__.py
|       |-- group.py
|       |-- index.py
|       |-- profile.py
|       `-- student.py
```

The `urls.py` under `My_Members` looks like:

```
from django.conf.urls import include
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import staticfiles_urlpatterns
from django.urls import path, re_path

from Members.views import index

urlpatterns = [
    path('accounts/', include('allauth.urls')),
    path('Members/', include('Members.urls')),
    path('Billing/', include('Billing.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    re_path(r'^$', index, name='index'),
]

urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()
```

Members/urls.py looks like:

```
from django.urls import path, re_path

from .views import index
from .views import profile
from .views import student

urlpatterns = [
    path('Members/Profile/<uuid:profile_id>/edit', profile.Update.as_view(),
         name="profile-update"),
    path('Members/Profile/<uuid:profile_id>/delete', profile.Delete.as_view(),
         name="profile-delete"),
    path('Members/Profile/create', profile.Create.as_view(),
         name="profile-create"),
    path('Members/Student/<uuid:student_id>/edit', student.Update.as_view(),
         name="student-update"),
    path('Members/Student/<uuid:student_id>/delete', student.Delete.as_view(),
         name="student-delete"),
    path('Members/Student/<uuid:account_id>/create', student.Create.as_view(),
         name="student-create"),
    path('Members/', index, name='index'),
]
```

and Billing/urls.py is:

```
from django.urls import path, re_path

from Members.views import index
from .views import account

urlpatterns = [
    path('Billing/Account/<uuid:profile_id>/create', account.Create.as_view(),
         name="account-create"),
    path('Billing/', index, name='index'),
]
```

The Billing urls file is new.  Since adding it, nearly all of the other URL patterns seem to fail. For example: the URL:

```
Members/Profile/ba73e105-325a-42d2-9476-20402d130189/edit
```

generated the error:

```
Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/Members/Profile/ba73e105-325a-42d2-9476-20402d130189/edit
Using the URLconf defined in CIAMembers.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

accounts/
Members/ Members/Profile/<uuid:profile_id>/edit [name='profile-update']
Members/ Members/Profile/<uuid:profile_id>/delete [name='profile-delete']
Members/ Members/Profile/create [name='profile-create']
Members/ Members/Student/<uuid:student_id>/edit [name='student-update']
Members/ Members/Student/<uuid:student_id>/delete [name='student-delete']
Members/ Members/Student/<uuid:account_id>/create [name='student-create']
Members/ ^$ [name='index']
Members/ Members/ [name='index']
Billing/
admin/
^$
^static\/(?P<path>.*)$
The current path, Members/Profile/ba73e105-325a-42d2-9476-20402d130189/edit, didn't match any of these.
```

The path I am targeting is right there at the top of error report's list.  What am I missing?

**Edit**

@jchung was correct.  I also forgot to terminate and restart the PyCharm debug session after editing a bunch of files.  Just restarting, as opposed to terminating and starting hangs on to old cached versions of the editied files.

Comment: Have you tried the inclusion without the path? You could take the `Members/` out of the paths in Members/urls.py or you could do the include with out path= in My_Members/urls.py  I think the error message shows it's LITERALLY searching for `/Members /Members/...`

Comment: Thanks, taking the paths off did the trick.